# what does this mean "Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded" In php

Tags: php

Why this message appears frequently ? Does it occurs when code is error or server is overloaded ? How can we decrease load in PHP server? How to solve this problem? please help me.

Comment: No it occurs if a script runs for more than 30 seconds

Comment: PS: Dont spam tags, surley you are not using all these frameworks on the same site at the same time!!!!!????????

Comment: And a google search is always a good idea before you ask a question. Or if all else fails a look at the manual

Comment: @RiggsFolly Or maybe they are and that's why it's taking too long...

Answer (score 1):

See [PHP's `set_time_limit(100);` method](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php):

> Set the number of seconds a script is allowed to run. If this is
>   reached, the script returns a fatal error. The default limit is 30
>   seconds or, if it exists, the max_execution_time value defined in the
>   php.ini.